# Need an if statement to stop MediaPlayer object only if it's playing

Tags: android, timer, android-mediaplayer

I have created a timer, so that when it finishes, music plays. But the song does not ever stop playing if the user presses the back button. So I tried to override the lifecycle method `onPause()`, which worked, so if the timer had finished and the music was actually playing - then using the back button stopped the music.

However, when a user tries to press the back button of their device **before** the timer finishes (and the music has not started yet), then I get a `null pointer exception` in the `onPause()` method.

What can be causing this? How do I write code that says "if MediaPlayer **is** playing, then stop and release it, otherwise do nothing". That is what I need conceptually. (Or there might be a better way to write it?)

**Here is my code snippet for the MediaPlayer in the timer's `onFinishes()` method, which makes the song start playing, when the timer finishes.** (`mpCease` is just a global variable that represents `mp`, so I can use it outside of `onFinish()` ).

```
public void onFinish() {
                mTextField.setText("BRAINS!!");
                // call some media function here
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(ZombieThemedActivity.this, R.raw.zombie_sound);
                mp.start();
                mpCease = mp;

                // This disables the pause/play button when timer ends
                Button disablePausePlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
                disablePausePlay.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

**Here is the onPause method written so far (it's not complete), which works really well to stop the music when the back button is pressed (only if it's already playing).**

```
@Override
    protected void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
        if (mpCease.isPlaying()) {
            mpCease.stop();
            mpCease.release();
        } else if (!mpCease.isPlaying()) {
            // it should do nothing to mpCease or to anything else
        }
    }
```

**LogCat** (when back button is pressed **before** timer is finished, it crashes).

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.azurespot.disastertimer.app/com.azurespot.disastertimer.app.themedactivities.ZombieThemedActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2838)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2794)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.azurespot.disastertimer.app.themedactivities.ZombieThemedActivity.onPause(ZombieThemedActivity.java:157)
            at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5106)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1225)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2794)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of `mp` and replace it with `mpCease`. Then check if that is `null`

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
    if (mpCease != null) //add a null check here
    {
        if (mpCease.isPlaying()) { 
            mpCease.stop();
            mpCease.release();
        // if this does nothing then the else isn't needed
        } else {
            // it should do nothing to mpCease or to anything else
        }
    }
```

You don't even have to get rid of `mp` but just check if `mpCease` is `null`. You don't initialize it until `onFinish()` of (I assume) a `CountDownTimer`. So, if they press back before it has finished then obviously it is `null`.

Comment: @donfuxx thanks, I missed that since it wasn't a deal breaker but I have edited with your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah sure, just doing some fine-tuning ;-) you forgot to remove then the (!mpCease.isPlaying()) part btw.

Comment: @donfuxx Ha, thanks again...it must be late. The `else` isn't even needed at all if, in fact, it isn't doing anything as the comment suggests.

Comment: Thanks @codeMagic!!! I had a feeling it was a simple fix, yet still a beginner, so it was escaping me. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. Just remember, if you don't initialize it before running a method on it then it is going to be `null` and this will be your result.

Comment: Ah, so I should initialize it in the onPause method?

Comment: No, there's no need to do that since you don't need it at that point. Just add the `null` check there. You could skip the `null` check and initialize it in `onCreate()` or somewhere before `onPause()` but what you have with my answer is fine. No need to initialize it before needed.