# Can someone explain to me how this method works?

Tags: java, android, keylistener

I have an app that when you press a button on the screen it plays an mp3 file. I want to make it so that if I press the back button or home button while the mp3 is playing, the song stops playing. I want to make a if statement that checks if the back/home button was pressed or not, and if either of the cases were true then call the myMediaPlayer.stop();

So far the only method that checks if the back button was pressed or not that I have found so far is:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

My problem is that I have no idea how in my if statement to call onKeyDown and check whether the back or home button were pressed.

Where do I find out what the keycode is and the event are that I need to pass to it?

**Here is the code that initializes and plays the mp3 file:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.default_activity_button);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd;
            afd = getAssets().openFd("sound.mp3");
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();enter code here
        }
    }

});
```

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
if(mp.isPlaying() == true && /* pseudo code*/BackButtonPressed == true/* pseudo code*/)
        {

        }
```

Comment: You don't need that. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463573/need-an-if-statement-to-stop-mediaplayer-object-only-if-its-playing/23463607#23463607) you can just stop it in `onPause()`

Answer (score 2):

This function is called automatically by the OS when any key down event occurs. So, you don't need to call it explicitly yourself. You just need to check for the key press that you need to determine. And the return statement tells the OS if you have handled the key press yourself or not. As in, when you return true the OS knows that you have successfully handled the event and it does need not do anything for that particular key press.

However, a more standard way of detecting the back key press is by overriding onBackPressed().

Something like this,

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       //stop playing mp3
    }
```

A more specific solution in your case would be to stop playing the music as soon as your Activity goes into Pause when the back key or the home button is pressed.

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
        //stop playing mp3
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: I'v added both to the bottom of my code, where should I call these methods?
Should I call them from the onCreate method?

Comment: When I call onBackPressed, the activity screen closes, while the mp3 continues to play.

Comment: You don't need to call them from anywhere. The OS will automatically call the functions. These are callbacks and are invoked when a particular event in the lifecycle of the Activity occurs.

Comment: You would also need to write the code to stop playing the mp3 inside onBackPressed.

Comment: I have added code from my main java file, to show you exactly what I'm dealing with. Where in here should I call the methods that you were talking about? I have tried implementing your examples above, however nothing seemed to work.

Comment: @Swayam, wouldn't stopping it in `onPause` stop it on any configuration change also?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about UI buttons or keyboard keys ? `onKeyDown` is to catch keyboard key presses.

If you want to catch button click you need to register a clickListener to your buttons.

If you want to catch keys you need to register an `OnKeyListener` in your view.

If you want to catch the special back button then it is sufficient to override the `onBackPressed()` method of your activity. So something like:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    // do want you want
    mp.stopPlaying();
  } else {
    // default behavior ?
    super.finish(); // dismiss the current activity
  }
}
```

should work.

Comment: I have added code from my main java file, to show you exactly what I'm dealing with. Any help?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that on any android device if you hit the back button (because all android phones have a back button) then the audio, if playing, stops playing.

Comment: Thank you, I got the back button to stop the audio on pressed. Now, is it the same way with the home button? Would I just override onHomePressed?

Comment: No, you should not try to modify the Home Button behavior, I think you can't with the standard API. Home Button is a kind of critical functionality, so you'd better try something else.

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyDown` is a public method called automatically by the Android system when a button is pressed on the device. You do not need to call it directly, but you do need to `@Override` it. The `KeyEvent` that the system passes to it is described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html). It contains a number of constants that refer to specific keys. I am not at home to test this, but I think you want something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)||(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME))&&(mp.isPlaying())) {
        mp.stop();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Edit: I don't have sufficient rep yet to comment on @Swayam's solution directly, but I believe implementing your solution in the `onPause` method would also stop the music in the event of an orientation change which would probably be undesirable.

Comment: I'v added @Swayam's solution to the bottom of my code, where should I call these methods? Should I call them from the onCreate method? When I call onBackPressed, the activity screen closes, while the mp3 continues to play.

Comment: Neither `onKeyDown` nor `onPause` should be called directly by your code. The Android system calls them for you when a key is pressed for `onKeyDown` or when your activity is paused for `onPause`. You may want to read up on the Android activity lifecycle
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: I have added code from my main java file, to show you exactly what I'm dealing with. Any help?

Comment: I missed your last comment. I've updated my answer to address your latest edit. This kind of turns the logic around from your last question so that, if the back key is pressed (which automatically calls onKeyDown), then it checks to see if mp is playing, and if it is, stops mp.